# See contents of long value in local storage in Safari

Tags: safari, local-storage, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

I'm trying to see the entire contents of a single value held in local storage in Safari (it's a long JSON object). When I view the key/value pair, the value is too long for the screen, and copying the row only copies the visible portion of the value. Is there a way to see the whole line?

Comment: Opened a radar regarding this (rdar://33487373 https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6076988368355328) as I feel this is a confusing / unexpected UI behavior. Feel free to dupe.

Answer (score 23):

You can access it using the console of the Safari Web Inspector.
Just enter the command:

```
localStorage.getItem('yourKeyNameHere')
```

and it will output the full local storage value to the console.

For session storage, use

```
sessionStorage.getItem('yourKeyNameHere')
```